# Angular2 Dart build gives "The selector "demo-app" did not match any elements" error

Tags: dart, angular, angular-dart

I'm porting an existing angular2 ts library to Dart.
Everything's working in Dartium but after building the app won't run in Chrome.

I'm getting an "The selector "demo-app" did not match any elements" error.

Not sure how to debug, any help would be appreciated!

Please see https://github.com/laagland/ng2-dart-pagination for the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter
```

should be the last transformer.
Also add this setting to the Angular transformer

```
 - angular2:
platform_directives: 'package:angular2/common.dart#CORE_DIRECTIVES'
```

See  https://github.com/kwalrath/angular.io/blob/d87fb0995aafe5da1c2be708986d74828b65d55c/public/docs/_examples/forms/dart/pubspec.yaml for an example.

You should try to avoid mirrors in browser applications because it causes code bloat. I didn't chech all your code, but I saw the `@MirrorsUsed` annotation. If you need reflection, use the reflectable package instead.

Comment: Hi Günter, this didn't work, but pointed me in the right direction. Without the rewriter the error is not showing, so I'll keep it out for the time being. Regarding the reflection, @MirrorsUsed isn't even working for me to keep the bloat down, so I'll look into the reflectable package. Thanks.